# DB2 quotes around numeric values

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have been wondering why DB2 SQL statements work even if there are quotes around numeric values.

For example, `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNO = '3'` where EMPNO is a number works as fine as `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNO = 3`? Why is this so? Aren't quotes for characters only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the DB will implicitly cast values if it needs to.

From the [v5r3 SQL Reference](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/systemi/v5r3/en_US/rbafzmst.pdf)
**What’s new for V5R3**

- Implicit conversion between strings and numeric data types